# How to reliably measure computed height of all combined child elements in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using `onLayout` to measure the height of a `View` in which are rendered an arbitrary number of child components containing multiple nested `View`s and at least one `Text` node. The returned height value is consistently just the value of the total vertical margin applied to the outermost `View`, however, and does not include the height of any other nodes, including the `Text` -- which has a nonzero height that I can successfully measure by using `onLayout` on it:

```
<View onLayout={/*only ever returns 40 as the height*/}>
  <View style={{marginBottom: 40}}>
    <Text>This node has a computed height of 60</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Is the issue here that `onLayout` is not firing consistently, or is it that the computed height will never actually include the computed heights of these child nodes? What's the preferred workaround for this type of situation?

Comment: I think that's a bug https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11650

Comment: @kai Have you tried using `yourViewRef.measure` instead of `onLayout`

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, .measure produces the same result.

Comment: @MahdiN thanks for the link! that sent me down the right path.

Comment: @Kai Can you please post the solution if you find one!

Comment: @MahdiN see the answer below. Unfortunately, I haven't found a real solution to the issue, but it can be worked around in some cases by moving Texts up to be immediate children of the View that you want to measure.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

It looks like there is indeed an undocumented issue with measuring the heights of React Native `View`s that contain `Text` nodes nested more than one level deep.

I moved the `Text` outside of its parent `View`, so that it's an immediate child of the node whose height I'm measuring, and the measured height is now correct:

```
<View onLayout={/*This now returns 100 as the height*/}>
  <View style={{marginBottom: 40}}>
  </View>
  <Text>This node has a computed height of 60</Text>
</View>
```

As far as a workaround, this will depend on the use case. In my situation I wound up having to apply various styles to each individual `Text` instead of using a wrapper.